# App getting freezed when doing work inside onDataChange() inside JobService class

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this everythingFunction() in an job service class, where i call this function inside the run method. My app freezes when i call this service, i know why this happens because i'm doing things inside on datachange method and i can't do it outside because some variable like allfriendsList and size cannot be accessed outside plus without eventlistener i cant even fetch data from DATABASE. So, i have no choice but to do it inside dataChange method. Can anybody help me how i cant solve this problem because i dont want my app to freeze?? Please, thank you!!!

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();
    friendUserRef = currentUserRef.child("Friends").child(currentUserID);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    doBackgroundWork(params);
    return true;
}

private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            everythingFunction();
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job Cancelled before complte");
    jobCancelled = true;
    return true;
}

public void dummy(String dum){
    LISTTTT.add(dum);
    int i = LISTTTT.size();
    Log.d(TAG, "dummy: " + i);
}

public void everythingFunction(){
    allFriendsLIST.clear();
    friendUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            final MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                friendsID = ds.getKey();
                allFriendsLIST.add(friendsID);

            }
            int size = allFriendsLIST.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                Log.d(TAG, "RUN:" + i);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);


                final String ID = allFriendsLIST.get(i);
                getMyLocation();
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                Log.d(TAG, "ID: " + ID);

                currentUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        int STATUS = snapshot.child("Users").child(ID).child("Status").getValue(int.class);
                        if (STATUS == 1){
                            Log.d(TAG, "SOMEONE IS ONLINE");
                            SystemClock.sleep(2000);

                            getMyLocation();
                            currentUserRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Status").setValue(1);

                            double LAT1 = snapshot.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Lat").getValue(double.class);
                            double LANG1 = snapshot.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Lang").getValue(double.class);
                            double LAT2 = snapshot.child("Users").child(ID).child("Lat").getValue(double.class);
                            double LANG2 = snapshot.child("Users").child(ID).child("Lang").getValue(double.class);
                            String friendName = snapshot.child("Users").child(ID).child("Name").getValue(String.class);

                            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                            Log.d(TAG, "LOCATION TAKEN");

                            double distance = mainScreen.sendDistance(LAT1,LANG1,LAT2,LANG2);
                            if (distance < 100){
                                int DIST = (int) distance;
                                Log.d(TAG, "DISTANCE: " + DIST);
                                sendNotification(friendName, DIST);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });

                Log.d(TAG, "LOC FUNC SUCCESFUL ");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "OUT OF LOOP");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase callbacks(`currentUserRef.addValueEventListener`) are executed on `main/UI thread`. You need to execute the code inside `onDataChange` on background thread separately.

Comment: But im already inside a job service , is it possible to run a thread inside a jobService class??